# How to load a View from SubDomain in dialog /popup window in MVC3?

Tags: c#-4.0, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Home screen with login button. When ever user clicks the Login button login view must open in dialog(popUp window). Here the twist is Home Screen and Login Screen are two different apps in two sub domains.
So I have to open Login View of auth.sample.com in dialog(PopUp window) from my.sample.com app. 
Sorry for the bad English. Please see the code below:

```
<p>
  <button type="submit" name="PopupLoginbutton" id = "PopupLoginbutton" value="Popbutton">Login</button> 
</p>
<div id="dialog" title="Login" style="overflow: hidden;"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'hi there',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
                           $(this).load("http://auth.sample.com/");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#PopupLoginbutton').click(function () {
                  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Try to add the JS assignment `document.domain = "auth.sample.com";` before the AJAX call in the my.sample.com app.

Comment: Tip: Test in every browser you can. This may vary by security settings, but Chrome and Firefox tend to accept some calls that IE and others not.

Comment: I added the code above, how I'm trying to access the auth.sample.com.

Answer (score 0):

Views can only be accessed if they are in the current MVC3 project. If all you want to do is show the login screen, you should just show the popup using the full URL (http://my.sample.com/login).

If you want to pass information to the login app, then you would have to use a form and POST/GET to the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your position correctly, you want to provide access to content or an area of your site, but only if users are logged in.  Are you looking to provide log in capabilities to your new site through the existing auth of your subdomain?

Unfortunately this won't work as you describe, if you're using common methods for authentication and authorization.  Logging into a different sub domain isn't going to get you where you're trying to go. I can't log into my bank and then check my email.

You can POST wherever you like or even use JS to load content from other sites/domains (if the end-users permissions/config allow), but your token in the browser to represent a logged in user won't carry over from one domain to the next.

There are several approaches, here are a couple of common ones:

1. Create a custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider. These would allow you to use the server-side logic you already have to your access your authentication service.
2. Configure your new site to use the same membership provider (and database) that the subdomain is using.
3. Build a web service and tokenization strategy to expose identity from your existing subdomain, and incorporate that into your site.

Number 2 is the easiest, if you own the subdomain.  Number 1 isn't too hard if you can wrap the calls to the membership service. If your subdomain is third party, however, and it locks up the user database then you won't have much luck here, unless they provide a means to wrap their login services.

Hope this helps some.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm using AD LDS , ASP.Net membership provider and default MVC Login Template to authenticate users in auth.sample.com and implemented authentication for my.sample.com successfully. When user access my.sample.com directly I have to show login view from auth.sample.com in the dialog or Popup box.